# ngx chart angular x Axis show time only 4 options

Tags: angular, charts, ngx-charts

i am new at ngx-charts .
 i am trying to show ngx-chart-line
i am trying to show in my xAxis  - time (format - hh:mm) .
but i want only to show  4  options on my xAxis
for ex : 10:00      12:00    16:00     19:00
i have tried fix it with loop and also with xAxisTickFormatting.
and in my  yAxis - value 
here is my code 
component ts

```
 this.chartData = [
      {
        name: "exAngular",
        series: [
          { value: "252.30", name: "19:20:00" },
          { value: "252.40", name: "19:20:00" },
          { value: "252.40", name: "16:20:00" },
          { value: "252.60", name: "15:20:00" },
          { value: "252.70", name: "13:19:00" },
          { value: "252.70", name: "13:19:00" },
          { value: "252.60", name: "12:19:00" },
          { value: "252.50", name: "12:19:00" },
          { value: "252.50", name: "12:19:00" },
          { value: "252.10", name: "12:17:00" },
          { value: "252.60", name: "11:16:00" },
          { value: "230.40", name: "11:16:00" },
          { value: "230.00", name: "11:16:00" },
          { value: "230.20", name: "11:16:00" },
          { value: "252.60", name: "11:14:00" },
          { value: "252.30", name: "11:14:00" },
          { value: "252.30", name: "11:14:00" },
          { value: "252.30", name: "11:14:00" },
          { value: "252.80", name: "11:14:00" },
          { value: "252.80", name: "09:58:00" },
          { value: "252.70", name: "09:58:00" },
          { value: "252.70", name: "09:58:00" },
          { value: "252.70", name: "09:58:00" },
          { value: "251.70", name: "09:55:00" },
          { value: "251.70", name: "09:55:00" },
          { value: "251.80", name: "09:55:00" },
          { value: "251.80", name: "09:55:00" },
          { value: "251.80", name: "09:53:00" },
          { value: "251.80", name: "09:52:00" },
          { value: "252.00", name: "09:52:00" },
          { value: "251.80", name: "09:52:00" },
          { value: "252.00", name: "09:51:00" },
          { value: "252.00", name: "09:49:00" },
          { value: "252.00", name: "09:49:00" },
          { value: "252.00", name: "09:49:00" },
          { value: "252.10", name: "09:49:00" },
          { value: "251.10", name: "09:47:00" },
          { value: "251.10", name: "09:47:00" },
          { value: "251.50", name: "09:46:00" }
        ]
      }
    ];`
```

here is my component html :

```
<div>
  <ngx-charts-line-chart [results]="chartData"
                         [scheme]="{domain: ['#000']}"
                         [xAxis]="true"
                         [yAxis]="true"
  </ngx-charts-line-chart>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter the data and assign it to chart

```
this.chartData[0].series = this.chartData[0].series.filter(x=> x.name.split(':')[0]==10 ||x.name.split(':')[0]==12||x.name.split(':')[0]==16||x.name.split(':')[0]==19  )
```

[Click here for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-line-chart-with-filtered-data)

Comment: thanks for your answer :) , i am cooding with nodeJs and db . i am getting chartData  from the server . and then using redux to update and get my data and in the component i am getting chartdata$ observable . i am trying to understand when and where (client/ server) because my data is dynamic and changing all the time